# spring-boot hotdeploy service / mbeans

Tags: jboss, spring-boot

I am researching migrating my application from jboss to spring-boot. I make heavy use of jboss hot deployment of services. Is there anything similar in spring boot? If not is there a framework that can help manage starting / stopping of services / mbeans.

Thanks

Comment: What's a typical use case? I.e. what do you need to switch on and off? Does it involve loading new code?

Comment: It does not involve loading new code. The basic use case is to be able to create, start  and stop an mbean. For example, we have service which creates outbound connections to different end points which are loaded from a DB based upon the name of the bean. i.e, A would connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.001 B would connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.002

Comment: Basically I'm looking for a way of loading starting / stopping mbeans at runtime.

Comment: You mean "a way that doesn't suck" (i.e. not the native JDK APIs)?

Comment: I guess i'm mostly talking about lifecycle management, i.e., I can start / stop numerous mbeans with the only difference being some config.

Comment: Spring has good support for static JMX (via `@ManagedResource` and friends). The APIs are there I guess if you want to create them manually at runtime, but I never did much of that.